# How to get refcursor result/output to show as text?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sys-refcursor

I'm trying to call a stored procedure in Oracle and show the results of the call, the problem is that it crashes on the line `FETCH v_cur into v_a;` with error: `ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match.`

I guess the output of the query does not match `v_a VARCHAR2(100)`, but I don't know what to put there instead. The stored procedure that's being called does a join of several tables and selects more than 20+ different columns belonging to different tables. So what I would want is to just view the output of the query without having to refer to each result column separately. How I would go and do this ?

I'm using SQL Navigator (not that important I guess).

```
DECLARE 
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_a   VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   pkg_get_results.get_rows(v_cur,to_date('2012/04/12', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),to_date('2012/04/12', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), '','','','');
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur into v_a;  -- what to put here ?
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_a );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cur;
END;
```

Comment: Actually it is important what product you're using. For SQL Nav, follow the instructions here: http://sqlnavigator.inside.quest.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2466

Comment: @IgbyLargeman - I'd vote this up if you posted it as an answer.

Comment: @JustinCave: Thanks, but it just doesn't feel right to me to post an answer which is basically "I googled it, here's what I found" without any elaboration from my own knowledge or research. Sadly I'm not working with Oracle these days and have no way (or time) to test.

Comment: @Igby, doesn't matter. You found an answer, and by creating an answer that can be accepted by the OP you make it easier for people with similar issues to find it. That's what makes SO so great. If an answer is buried in comments it's impossible for the OP to accept, and harder for people to find.

Comment: @DCookie: that's true. I still feel like I'm just adding a redundant result to google searches, but I can see both sides of the argument. I'll post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Navigator does have the ability to do this for you. How to do it exactly depends on your version of Navigator, and it's conceivable (though I don't know) some versions may not have it.

Instructions can be found in this thread: http://sqlnavigator.inside.quest.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2466

Incidentally, Toad also has this ability.

Comment: So there is no way to do this in eg. SQLPlus ?

Comment: Sure. You could define a bind variable before the PL/SQL block and print it out afterwards. Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359%5F01/server.111/b31189/ch5.htm#autoId34